# Is there an endpoint to delete or remove a task in Asana?

Tags: asana

I can't seem to find the remove / delete task endpoint in the Asana API.

http://developers.asana.com/documentation/#tasks

Is this functionality available to developers yet? If so, how can I remove a task?

Comment: In the meanwhile you can get a similar effect by removing the task from all of its projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

This is not yet supported. We do intend to add this functionality sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a end point for deleting tasks: https://developers.asana.com/docs/delete-a-task